# S3 Put event and lambda concurrency

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

From:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-core-components.html#intro-core-components-event-sources

> For all other event sources and invocation mechanisms, Lambda executes
>   your function concurrently for each request or event. You can
>   estimate your concurrent requests using this formula: requests per
>   second * function duration. For example, if your function is
>   subscribed to an Amazon S3 bucket with 10 writes per second, and each
>   function execution takes 3 seconds on average, your function has 10 *
>   3 = 30 concurrent executions.

Why is 30 concurrent functions being called? Shouldn't it be **up to/average of** 30 concurrent executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can estimate your concurrent requests using this formula

Yes, that is an estimate of the typical/average concurrency.    Your function only **actually has** that many **if** the other conditions hold true.